# How to search for the 'double click' shortcut?

Tags: shortcut

In preference, i tried to find any hotkey which using 'double click' , but how can i do this properly ? i tried to use keyword 'double' or 'dbl' but nothing shows up, in fact i check manually there's some hotkey using double clicking. Does anyone know ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can search for a hotkey using double click in the latest version of Blender (2.79b). I created one using double click but even searching dbl-Left Mouse didn't work (which was displayed in the key binding area). Maybe it has something to do with not being able to assign a double click shortcut by double clicking.
[image: The shortcut being created, notice that it says dbl-Left Mouse in the key binding area]

[image: Blender not finding any search results]